# Rows to comma separated, vertical to horizontal, values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, csv

How to get rows as comma separated values.

```
select [name] from sys.objects where type='u'
```

i get this :

```
DropDownList
SubActivityDetails
Report
Employees
UserMaster
ProjectMaster
```

i want this :

```
DropDownList,SubActivityDetails,Report,Employees,UserMaster,ProjectMaster
```

in a single Query only

And also in this case

```
select [name],[object_id] from sys.objects where type='u'
```

I get this:

```
DropDownList    66099276
SubActivityDetails  197575742
Report  254623950
Employees   270624007
```

But I want this:

```
  ["SubActivityDetails",197575742],
  ["Report",254623950],
  ["Employees",270624007]
```

so that its similar to json.

And there would be lot of data, so performance is a major concern!

which is better

case 1 :

DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(MAX) 
begin
select  @Val = isnull(@val + ',' + [name],[name])
from    sys.objects
where   type='u' 
SELECT @Val 
end

case 2 :

DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(MAX) 
begin
select  @Val = COALESCE(@val + ',' + [name],[name])
from    sys.objects
where   type='u' 
SELECT @Val 
end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at something like this

```
DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(MAX)
select  @Val = COALESCE(@val + ',' + [name], [name])
from    sys.objects 
where   type='u' 

SELECT @Val
```

Ok, so for the second query we can try

```
DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(MAX)

select  @Val = COALESCE(@val + ',' + '["' + [name] + '",' + CAST([object_id] AS VARCHAR(50)) + ']', '["' + [name] + '",' + CAST([object_id] AS VARCHAR(50)) + ']') 
from    sys.objects 
where   type='u' 

SELECT @Val
```

Comment: Ohh wow! that works  fine but what can you recommend me for case 2

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but which once better

case 1 :
DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(MAX) 
begin
select  @Val = isnull(@val + ',' + [name],[name])
from    sys.objects  
where   type='u' 
SELECT @Val 
end
case 2 :
DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(MAX) 
begin
select  @Val = COALESCE(@val + ',' + [name],[name])
from    sys.objects  
where   type='u' 
SELECT @Val 
end

Comment: In this case they are both the same. COALESCE differs from ISNULL that you can specify more that 2 values to look through. Have a look at the documentation.